# How can I get a substring of a row in a column returned by loc?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, copy

I have a dataframe (df) which has the column 'Date Created'.

I need to splice the string inside 'Date Created' so that I'm only left with the numerical day instead of the entire datetime string (For example, I want to cut 'Sun Mar 03 2020 11:52 pm' to "2020/03/"+ 'string in Date Created'[8:10] (9th and 10th character).

I tried this but I get a copy warning:

```
for x in range(len(df)):
  df.iloc[x]['date'] = "202003" + (df.iloc[x]['Date Created'])[8:10]
```

I go to the documentation and it has instructions on how to use loc to get substrings but they do so for a very specific example case that doesn't apply to my code.

I tried this then:

```
df['date'] = ''
df.loc[:,['Date Created']] = "202003"+ (df.loc[:,['Date Created']])[8:10]
```

But this also doesn't work. Can someone please help on how I can get the 9th and 10th character of each row of Date Created and assign that to a new column (or even replace the existing value in Date Created)? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

I made up this dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date Created": ["Sun Mar 03 2020 11:52 pm", 
                                    "Sun Mar 08 2020 11:52 pm",
                                    "Sun Mar 09 2020 11:52 pm"]})
```

So with

```
df.loc[:, "Date Created"] = "202003" + df["Date Created"].str[8:10]
```

You'll get this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach would be accessing `day` field of `datetime` object:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date Created": [
  "Sun Mar 01 2020 11:52 pm", 
  "Sun Mar 08 2020 11:52 pm",
  "Sun Mar 15 2020 11:52 pm"
]})

df
```

Output:

```
    Date Created
0   Sun Mar 01 2020 11:52 pm
1   Sun Mar 08 2020 11:52 pm
2   Sun Mar 15 2020 11:52 pm
```

.

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date Created']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date Created']).month
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date Created']).day
df['formatted'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date Created']).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
df
```

Output:

```
    Date Created                year    month   day formatted
0   Sun Mar 01 2020 11:52 pm    2020    3       1   2020/03/01
1   Sun Mar 08 2020 11:52 pm    2020    3       8   2020/03/08
2   Sun Mar 15 2020 11:52 pm    2020    3       15  2020/03/15
```